# Emulate a click on a p:selectOneRadio

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

i have a p:selectOneRadio

```
<p:selectOneRadio id="radioTpPunto" value="#{geoWebModel.radioPuntoBtnValue}" widgetVar="selectTipoRicerca">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="P. di Fermo" itemValue="1" />                                                   
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="P. di Destinazione" itemValue="2" />                                            
   <p:ajax listener="#{geoRefCtr.doAction('radioPuntoChange')}" update=":geoForm:panelFiltroPosizione"/>    
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

And everything is working fine when I click the 2 options : my method is called and my model is updated.

Now, I want to "emulate" this behaviour using Javascript and I've tried using something like:

```
selectTipoRicerca.jq.find('input:radio[value=2]').trigger('click.selectOneRadio');
```

My backing bean's method is called but the value of my model isn't updating.

Any clues ?

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Can you give a little bit more background information?

Comment: Because I need to do 2 different searches at the same time : these searches are also based on that selectOneRadio value.

Answer (score -2):

You can give that specific radio an ID and then use:

```
document.getElementById("myRadio").click();
```

this will trigger just as if a user clicked the radio button.

If you're using jQuery, you can shorten it to:

```
$("myRadio").click();
```